# 'username_exists' still returns an ID even after deleting record from the database?

Tags: users, mysql

Is there some kind of MySQL query cache turned on by default or something? I am trying to work on a user import script and I am seeing some strange results from the `username_exists`function after I delete records from the `wp_users` table. After I delete the records when I call `username_exists` Wordpress is still returning the ID for the deleted user instead of `false`. Odd. What am I missing?

Comment: Why not go simple and `$username_exists = false === username_exists( $username ) ? false : ! empty( get_userdata( (int) username_exists( $username ) ) );`? if a user is deleted their associated data should be empty..

Comment: Even better `$username_exists = ! empty( get_user_by( 'slug', $username ) );`..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, WordPress uses `$wp_object_cache` which is an instance of [`WP_Object_Cache`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_object_cache/) to save on trips to the database.

Trace back [`username_exists()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/username_exists/#source-code) function, you will notice that [`get_user_by()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_user_by/) uses [`WP_User::get_data_by()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_user/get_data_by/#source-code) which return user data from `$wp_object_cache` immediately without checking if that user exists in database. Note that `$wp_object_cache` is stored in memory.

It means that if you deleted an user record directly in your database without cleaning up user cache, user data is still available. That's the problem.

So what you're missing?

1. Missing to [delete user the right way](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_delete_user/#source-code).
2. Missing to [clean user cache](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/clean_user_cache/).

Comment: Thank you. My issue is I've implemented external object caching using Redis and Eric Mann's [Redis Object Cache](https://github.com/ericmann/Redis-Object-Cache). I tried using a `clean_user_cache()` method call, but that did not work for clearing the Redis Object Cache. I can do a `redis-cli flushall` on the command line to flush the Redis cache after running the SQL restore and that works. Now, if I can, I'd like to check and clear the object cache for Redis from inside my Wordpress plugin. I'm having a hard time finding any documentation for that. Is it possible?

Comment: @AdamChristianson [`Redis Object Cache`](https://github.com/ericmann/Redis-Object-Cache) has the same functions as `WP_Object_Cache` so `clean_user_cache` should work normally. Have you tried [`wp_cache_flush()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_cache_flush/)?

Answer (score 1):

Caching can be anywhere, starting with request caching on mysql components side (unlikely to impact in this case), and object caching on wordpress side.

You are probably doing something wrong in your code, but it is always better to use the API (or wordpress admin as a front end to it) to delete things then to try to delete them by directly accessing the DB. It is not only caching that might give you problems but also user meta and other configuration settings that you are not going to take into account.

Comment: Thanks Mark. I am removing the records via the Wirdpress admin, so I should be OK there. This is a Dev environment, so I shouldn't have any caching set up, but I'll keep looking.